# creating rectangular mesh (list of line segments) from a 2D array of points, in numpy

Tags: multidimensional-array, numpy, mesh

I have an MxNx2 array of 2D points, where each point represents the center of a measured property of a grid. The graphical representation is below, with white points being the positions:

[image]

The point structure is like this (shape: MxNx2):

```
[[[xij, yij], [xij, yij], ...]],
 [[xij, yij], [xij, yij], ...]],
 [[xij, yij], [xij, yij], ...]],
 [ ..., ...., ............... ],
 [[xij, yij], [xij, yij], ...]]]
```

The desired output would be like this:

```
[[[x1, x2], [y1, y2]],
 [[x1, x2], [y1, y2]],
 ....................,
 [[x1, x2], [y1, y2]]
```

So that I could plot every segment one by one (using each pair of x,y positions) like this:

[image]

I have trying something similar to:

```
segments = []
for row in xrange(a.shape[0] - 1):
    for col in xrange(a.shape[1] - 1):
        here = a[row, col]
        below = a[row+1, col]
        right = a[row, col+1]
        segments.extend(((here, right), (here, below)))
```

but that leaves the right and bottom edges uncovered. Also, I suspect this is a somewhat "dumb", non-vectorized, brute-force way of doing it, it seems to be a common enough problem to have perhaps a mesh-creating function for it.

Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by adding segments separately for axis:

```
for row in xrange(a.shape[0]):
    segments.extend( (a[row, col], a[row, col+1]) for col in xrange(a.shape[1] - 1) )
for col in xrange(a.shape[1]):
    segments.extend( (a[row, col], a[row+1, col]) for row in xrange(a.shape[0] - 1) )
```

Or with `zip()`:

```
s1 = (a.shape[0]*(a.shape[1]-1), 2)
s2 = (a.shape[1]*(a.shape[0]-1), 2)
segments = list(zip( a[:,:-1].reshape(s1), a[:,1:].reshape(s1))) + \
           list(zip( a[:-1,:].reshape(s2), a[1:,:].reshape(s2)))
```

Comment: The first one hits target, and I even believe that it could be transformed in one nested list comprehension per axis to get two one-liners and that's it. The second code is a bit hard to read, but is also a very clever use of python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested, I modified the code I was using and it now works, perhaps not so elegantly or eficiently, but...

```
pairs = []
for row in xrange(pointarray.shape[0]):
    for col in xrange(pointarray.shape[1]):
        here = pointarray[row, col]
        if row < pointarray.shape[0]-1:
            below = pointarray[row+1, col]
            pairs.append((here, below))
        if col < pointarray.shape[1]-1:
            right = pointarray[row, col+1]
            pairs.append((here, right))
```